# How can I get from Tegel Airport to Bernau (bei Berlin) on Sunday evening?

Tags: germany, airport-transfer, transportation, berlin, txl

I have a flight tomorrow, Sunday, that arrives at Tegel at 8 pm and cannot find a way to get to Bernau bei Berlin where my hotel is located.

I saw this option: via u-bahn from Tegel station to Nanturkundemuseum, after that walk to Berlin Nordbahnhof and then onto the S2 line to Bernau. I'm not sure if the s-bahn is available late night, after 9-9:30 pm, which is probably the actual time of my arrival there.

Is this the best way to do it? If not, how else can it be done?

Comment: Depending on when you get out of the airport… there's an RE3 train from Hauptbahnhof to Schwedt (via Bernau) leaving 21:15; the TXL bus takes 16 mins from the airport to Hauptbahnhof. It's not the fastest route, but probably the more grandiose, with the giant Hauptbahnhof building and the nicer regional train.

Comment: You might want to check: http://fahrinfo.bvg.de/Fahrinfo/bin/query.bin/en?from=+Flughafen+Tegel+%28Airport%29+%28Berlin%29&to=+S+Bernau+Bhf&date=09.07.2017&time=22%3A00&timesel=depart&lang=en

Comment: 21:30 is not "late at night" where the S-Bahn is concerned. The last departures are usually around 01:00.

Comment: When you use journey planners, be sure to enter your starting point specifically as the _airport_, and not the residential neighborhood of Tegel, which is a long way from the terminal. If the journey planner doesn't specifically say "airport" or "Flughafen", then it's the wrong place!

Comment: Google maps has very accurate public transport data including busses and ferries in Berlin. [Here is your search](https://goo.gl/maps/ZCpsE8sv6SK2). The transport network is quite reliable (unless you go to work with it every day). At some point at night trains and busses are rarer, but there is always a way to go somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- At Tegel, enter the Bus TXL in the direction of S+U Alexanderplatz. This bus leaves every 6-7 minutes, so just go into the first bus in that direction. Leave the Bus at S+U Brandenburger Tor.
- At Brandenburger Tor, take the S2 rapid transit train towards S Bernau. This train leaves every 20 minutes, so again the best bet is to simply take the next available train. Depending on where your hotel is, leave at S Bernau-Friedenstal or S Bernau.
- "S+U" means a station for rapid transit trains (S-Bahn) and undergroud trains (U-Bahn). "S" is just the rapid transit train. At Brandenburger Tor, follow the signs for S-Bahn platform 2, not for the U-Bahn.
- You can buy a ticket for €3,40 from the bus driver.
- If there are delays, the last possible connection would be the Bus X9 leaving Tegel at 0:29 Monday morning, with transfers at Jungfernheide to the S41 and at Gesundbrunnen to the RE3 local train.

Comment: might be worth noting that both S+U can go underground, despite their names and it's best to keep coins at hand when buying a ticket from the bus driver

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat confused by the recommended route. The U-Bahn does not go to Tegel Airport (TXL). It is served by local and express buses. Looking at [the map](http://www.s-bahn-berlin.de/pdf/VBB-Liniennetz.pdf) a reasonable routing is the TXL Express Bus to the <s>Hauptbahnhof</s> [EDIT: As @o.m. indicates, this should probably be Brandenburger Tor], change to the S2 for Bernau. You can also save distance but change twice by leaving the bus for the S41 at Beusselstr. The [bus](http://www.bvg.de/images/content/linienverlaeufe/LinienverlaufBusTXL.pdf) runs until 00:30. The S2 is shown on the night route map, so presumably has 24 hours service. There are also regional trains (for example RE3) from the Hauptbahnhof to Bernau. You can ride them with tickets for the tariff zone ABC too.

Comment: Are you sure this is still current regarding the Hauptbahnhof transfer?

Comment: The OP probably typed Berlin-Tegel into a journey planner, not knowing that is the name of an S-Bahn station 6-7 not very walkable kilometers from the airport terminal. (And if you start _there_, walking to the few hundred meters to U-Bf Alt-Tegel is not out of the question).

Comment: @o.m. No, I was just going from the indicated map. I didn't use the Journey Planner.